# ¿Cómo redireccionar con Iron-Router en Meteor?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, meteor

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en meteor y tengo este error :

```
Error: No route found named "perfiles"
```

Este es mi script:

main.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import '../lib/routes/routes';
import './main.html';
import './perfiles.html';

Modal.allowMultiple=true;


if(Meteor.isClient){

  Template.registro.events({ 
    'submit #register-form': function(event, template) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var nombreVar = template.find('#nombre').value; 
      var apellidoVar = template.find('#apellido').value;
      var emailVar = template.find('#email').value; 
      var telefonoVar = template.find('#telefono').value;
      var password1Var = template.find('#password1').value; 
      var password2 = template.find('#password2').value;

      //console.log(password1Var+nombreVar+apellidoVar+emailVar+telefonoVar+password2);

      var userObject = { 

        name : nombreVar, 
        firts_name : apellidoVar,
        email :emailVar,
        phone : telefonoVar,
        password : password1Var

      }; 

      Accounts.createUser(userObject,function(err){ 
        console.log(Meteor.user());
      });

    } 

   ,'submit #login-form':function(event,template){
     event.preventDefault();
     var emailVar = template.find('#login-email').value; 
     var password1Var = template.find('#login-password').value; 
     console.log(emailVar+password1Var);
     var userLogin = { 

      email :emailVar,
      password : password1Var

    }; 
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar,password1Var);
    Modal.hide(template);
    console.log("logueado");
    Router.go("perfiles");

   }
 });

 Template.registro.events({
   'click #Logout':function(event,template){

    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.logout();
    console.log("chau");

   }

 });


}
```

routes.js

```
import { Router } from 'meteor/iron:router';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';


//Router.route('/layouts');
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate :'registro',

})



Router.onBeforeAction(function(){

  if (!Meteor.userId()){

      Router.go('registros');
      this.next();

  }else{

      if(Router.current().route.getName() === 'registro'){

              Router.go('perfiles');
      }
     this.next();
  }
});
```

Carpetas y archivos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]